# Force FAST ESP to search within scope fields when query does not specify scopes explicitly

Tags: fast-esp, fastsearch

This is a question to any FAST ESP developers out there :) I've noticed that documents with matches within scope fields are not returned when a simple query is issued.

Say, I have a document with a scope field 'Places', that contains the value 'London, UK' within one of the subscopes. If a query 'London' is issued, the document is not returned. If the query is changed to 'places:London', then the document gets found.

Since we have multiple scope fields, rewriting the initial query to include all of the scope names would be a pain, especially with advanced search operators.

How can you force FAST ESP to return such a document even if the query does not define the scope explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't, The Scope root is set in in the index profile.  Your best bet would be to have a common scope and use that instead.